# gromit / gromit-mpx doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, presentation

I've installed `gromit` and `gromit-mpx`, but nothing happens when I launch them.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/gromit.1.html

https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-gromit-mpx/

```
wolf@linux:~$ sudo apt install gromit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gromit is already the newest version (20041213-9build1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.

wolf@linux:~$ sudo apt install gromit-mpx 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gromit-mpx is already the newest version (1.3-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
```

Nothing happens when I launch them:

```
wolf@linux:~$ gromit
wolf@linux:~$ gromit-mpx 
wolf@linux:~$
```

Any idea how to use this tool?

Comment: Which display server do you use - Xorg or Wayland? Please show the output of `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`. What is your current desktop environment? Please add output of `echo $XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP`.

Comment: After running `gromit`, did you press the **Pause** key? The **Pause** key is reached through **Fn+PgUp** in my notebook.

Comment: In debian `pkill gromit-mpx` then issue `gromit-mpx` works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`gromit` uses the <kbd>Pause</kbd> key to control it. When you run `gromit` from command line or from its desktop icon, it starts and waits in the background.

- To activate it you need to press the <kbd>Pause</kbd> key. Pressing <kbd>Pause</kbd> once more will make `gromit` wait in the background again. So, this key acts as a way to toggle painting.
- Use the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd> key to clear whatever you have drawn.
- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd> to toggle the view of whatever you have drawn.
- Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd> to stop and quit `gromit`.

Note: Most notebook keyboards will **not** have a *separate* <kbd>Pause</kbd> key. On my keyboard the <kbd>Pause</kbd> key is reached using the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> key. So, to quit `gromit` for example on my notebook, I have to use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> on my keyboard.

See [the man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/gromit.1.html) on how to change the <kbd>Pause</kbd> key to something more easy accessible.

---

`gromit` itself is not very useful, since it starts drawing from the left-top corner of your screen and connects with straight lines the area where you have released your mouse and then pressed the mouse key again. So, it is better to use `gromit-mpx` which allows you "to make multi-pointer annotations on your screen". `gromit-mpx` uses the <kbd>F9</kbd> key instead of the <kbd>Pause</kbd> key, so:

- Press <kbd>F9</kbd> key to toggle painting.
- Use the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> key to clear whatever you have drawn.
- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to toggle the view of whatever you have drawn.
- Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to stop and quit `gromit-mpx`.

The <kbd>F9</kbd> key can be changed to something else. See [its man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/gromit-mpx.1.html).